# Laggy custom cursor is Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cursor

Making a custom cursor in flash as3, I have replaced the cursor with a broomstick (simple vector movieclip). The code is the standard custom cursor code below:

```
private function listeners():void  {
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, attachBroom);
}

private function attachBroom(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    broomStick.x = e.stageX - 10;
    broomStick.y = e.stageY - 5;
    e.updateAfterEvent();
}
```

SWF can be found [here](http://megaswf.com/s/2472537). The cursor is fine while on top of the actual smoke alarm graphic, but when it goes over the background, it lags severely when the mouse is moved at a 'fast' speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead of yours

```
private function listeners():void  {
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, attachBroom);
}

private function attachBroom(e:Event):void 
{
    broomStick.x = stage.mouseX - 10;
    broomStick.y = stage.mouseY - 5;
}
```

the logic is same but ENTER_FRAME event is faster than MOUSE_EVENTS. Also there is no updataAfterEvent for ENTER_FRAME.

Comment: To clarify, ENTER_FRAME runs less times per second than MOUSE_MOVE (assuming you don't manually adjust the framerate to be some really high amount), making it less of a resource burden. That being said, you should have a look at the answer explaining Native Cursors, as those integrate with the mouse at the OS level and do not require any special resource hogging events to show a fake mouse cursor.

Answer (score 6):

There is much better way to do custom cursors nowadays.

since Flash Player 10.2, you can use the Native Cursors, which are using the native OS resources.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/native-mouse-cursors.html